# Assigning multiple queues in python

Tags: python, queue, python-import

I want to assign values of dictionary as queue but I don't want to create a loop.

```
    import queue
queues = dict({el:"q"+str(el) for el in range(5)})
queue for queue in queues.values() = queue.Queue()
```

It gives me an error. How can I do this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import queue

queues = dict({el: "q" + str(el) for el in range(5)})

q2 = queue.Queue()
q2.queue = queue.deque(queues.values())

print(list(q2.queue))
```

Output:

```
['q0', 'q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4']
```

Comment: When I want to put something into these queues it gives an error for example, list(q2.queue)[a].put(line)

Comment: It says that str object has no attribute "put"